# $f(x)\to A(x\to\infty)$ and $f''(x)+\lambda f'(x)\leq M.$How to prove $f'(x)\to 0(x\to\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f(x)\in C^{2}(0,\infty)$ ,$f(x)\to A(x\to\infty)$ and $f''(x)+\lambda f'(x)\leq M.$How to prove $f'(x)\to 0(x\to\infty)$?

It's easy to see that without loss of generality we can assume $f(\infty)=0.$So if we can prove $f'(x)$ is convergent at $\infty$,we can use $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(t)\to 0$ to show $f'(\infty)=0.$

And I know another useful lemma.If $f(\infty)=A$,and $f''(x)$ is bounded then $f'(\infty)=0.$

But I found these lemmas don't work here.So how to solve this problem?Does it have any background?Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Is anything given about the signs of $\lambda$ and $M$? Can we assume that both are positive?